# How to access users id on creation?

Tags: laravel-5, orm, relational-database

Please, I want to get the id of the registered user in my levelone table as soon as it the user is registered.

I want to use it on line 61 of my IDE or can that be done with one on one relationship automatically?

[image: RegisterController]

[image: upper part of the code]

It is returned at the bottom of the code but with user variable.

This is the screenshot of my LevelOneModel:

[image: LevelOneModel Screenshot]

Thanks. You have been helpful

Comment: `$user` is now just going to equal `$levelone`.

Comment: Please how can I workaround that?

Comment: I've already shown you one way to do it in my answer...

Comment: I followed it exactly the way you directed it still throws error.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do something like:

```
$levelone = new LevelOneModel();

$levelone->user()->associate(User::create([
    'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
    'last_name'  => $data['last_name'],
    'email'      => $data['email'],
    'password'   => bcrypt($data['password']),
]));

$levelone->save();

return $levelone->user;
```

Hope this helps!

---

For the sake of it though I would just suggest doing:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name'  => $data['last_name'],
        'email'      => $data['email'],
        'password'   => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $levelone = new LevelOneModel();

    $levelone->user()->associate($user);

    $levelone->save();

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: FatalThrowableError in SessionGuard.php line 407:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\LevelOneModel given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\webemplo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 35

Comment: @JustinChinonsoObi  You need to return the `User` from this method. I've updated my answer.

Comment: please kindly see my screenshot above.  Everything was returned at the end of the code. I'm not sure that is the correct way to do it.